# How do I use test resources (like a fixed yaml file) with pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I've looked around the docs on the pytest website, but haven't found a clear example of working with 'test resources', such as reading in fixed files during unit tests. Something similar to what http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2007/06/proper-way-to-access-file-resources-in.html describes for Java.

For example, if I have a yaml file checked in to source control, what is the right way to write a test which loads from that file? I think this boils down to understanding the right way to access a 'resource file' on the python equivalent of the classpath (PYTHONPATH?).

This seems like it should be simple. Is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "resource file" is whatever definition you give to it in python (in Java, resource files can be bundled into jar files with ordinary Java classes, and Java provides library functions to access this information).

An equivalent solution might be to access the PYTHONPATH environment variable, define your "resource file" as a relative path, and then troll the PYTHONPATH looking for it.  Here's an example:

```
pythonpath = os.env['PYTHONPATH']
file_relative_path = os.path.join('subdir', 'resourcefile') // e.g. subdir/resourcefile
for dir in pythonpath.split(os.pathsep):
    resource_path = os.path.join(dir, file_relative_path)
    if os.path.exists(resource_path):
        return resource_path
```

This code snippet returns a full path for the first file that exists on the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you are looking for is **pkg_resources** or **pkgutil**. For example, if you have a module within your python source called "resources", you could read your "resourcefile" using:

```
with open(pkg_resources.resource_filename("resources", "resourcefile")) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
```

or:

```
 with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as outfile:
        outfile.write(pkgutil.get_data("resources", "resourcefile"))
```

The latter even works when your "script" is an executable zip file. The former works without needing to unpack your resources from an egg.

Note that creating a subdirectory of your source does not make it a module. You need to add a file named `__init__.py` within the directory for it to be visible as a module for the purposes of pkg_resources and pkgutil. `__init__.py` can be empty.

Comment: Not a good solution if you use tox since it installs your package in a virtualenv using sources created by `python setup.py sdist`. If you use pkg_resources then you should make sure setup.py copies your files during installation.

Comment: This works just fine for virtualenvs provided you are running in your virtualenv. This is precisely the scenario I use. If the file in question isn't installed in your pylib then it isn't a "pkg_resource". If your setup.py configures setuptools to find your packages - as is the case in all projects I work with - then the existence of __init__.py will ensure it is packaged in your egg.

Comment: I think instead of "module" you mean "package".

Comment: Yeah I meant package - I'm a polyglot and often terms from one language get used when I'm talking about another.